# How to give admin access to private repository when there is no role options

Tags: git, github

In my GitHub private repo->settings->manage access. I can see collaborators but there is no role options next to them. How do I give them admin access?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to do in a simple user account (public or private). You have admin access as the only owner. There is a different type of repository that could be useful in your case - an organization account. With it, you can grant admin rights to other members. More information about types of accounts here: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/getting-started-with-github/access-permissions-on-github